# Discord.JS / NodeJS | Getting an error with args

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an arg error with this code btw I tried making a config with subcommands into it.

```
if (command = "config") {
    if(!args[1]) args[1] = "Not provided";

    if (args[1] = "ott"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedtitle` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Title saved as: " + args[2]);
    }

    if (args[1] = "otm"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedmessage` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Message saved as: " + args[2]);
    }
}
```

That's my code with the args and it gives me this error.

```
(node:13756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\index.js:37:17)
at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Topsmoks\Desktop\miz - Copy\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Used Packages:

- Discord^12.3.1
- enmap^5.7.0
- better-sqlite3^7.1.0

Comment: can you share index.js for reference?

Comment: I Don't want to share the full index cause its a custom bot that I coded my self and got only this error. So if you could explain What could cause that problem?

Comment: How is `args` initialized?

Comment: According to the log `Desktop\miz - Copy\index.js:37:17` in index.js line 37.
a variable of type `const` is used which is reassigned. That's why it is causing this error

Comment: I have this in my command manager that const the args.                                                               const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

Comment: aRvi Line 37 it's the first line of what I posted above all those comments.

Comment: @Topsmoks please check my answer once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning a value to args and command, wich I suppose are constant:

```
if (command = "config") {
    if(!args[1]) args[1] = "Not provided";

    if (args[1] = "ott"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedtitle` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Title saved as: " + args[2]);
    }

    if (args[1] = "otm"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedmessage` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Message saved as: " + args[2]);
    }
}
```

Instead you should compare them using == or ===:

```
if (command == "config") {
    if(!args[1]) args[1] = "Not provided";

    if (args[1] == "ott"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedtitle` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Title saved as: " + args[2]);
    }

    if (args[1] == "otm"){
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}-openedtickedmessage` , args[2])
        message.channel.send("Opened Ticket Message saved as: " + args[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`command` will also be of type `const`

you have used

```
if (command = "config") {
```

It should be

```
if (command == "config") {
```

similarly, all `if` cases should also be corrected